# How to create a sticky footer & header with Angular Material

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to create a web page using angular-material 8. The idea is that both the header and the footer should be sticky and content should fill rest of the page. A, for me, standard application page.

Despite googling I have not succeeded. Too many suggestions, version, etc, and no one works for me, so I am asking for help here.

To start, this is my index.html with corresponding style.css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    

    <title>Angular 7 User Registration and Login Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body class="body">
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>

</html>

---------------------------



.body {
  background: black;
}
```

Then I have the application component.

```html
--------------------------

<div  class="page">

<app-navigation class="header" ></app-navigation>
 

<router-outlet class="content"></router-outlet>

 
<app-footer class="footer" ></app-footer>
</div>


---------------------------

.page {
    margin: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
  }


  .content { 
    width: 100%;
    background:salmon;
  }

.footer, header{
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
    background:gray;
}

-----------------------------
```

This code gives the following result in a chrome browser.[image]

Please notice the scrollbar. It seems that header, content, and footer are bigger than the available area in the browser. 
How come??

Also, notice the black area. Black is from the "body" class. How come it is visible ?? Should it not be covered by the "page" class?

I really, really would appreciate some help here.

Comment: can you pls add your application to https://stackblitz.com/ it would be easier to fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your body to hide that black screen. seems your body is getting a padding by default;

```
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

2nd remove `min-height: 100vh;` from your page and add `height: 100vh;` to  your body class i guess this will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I've noticed another problem. If I add text into the content component and shrinks the browser page,, footer stays sticky until the "added" is text reached then it goes "floating" ( same behavior as on this page).

I had expected that the content  would have the scrollbar visible but footer and header still visible.

Comment: if you add your code on online editor i can try to fix this

Comment: so you want your header and footer always sticky and only content will be srollable right?

Comment: check out your code. I have fixed that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knunti

Comment: Not quite as I wanted it. If you shrink the browser window until the footer reaches the text in "content",  the footer is turned floating. The browser have enabled the scrollbar for the complete page.  --- I would like to only enable scrollbar for the content component and that the footer still should be visible. Footer should never go away.

Comment: Ok right now footer is showing up all the time. If you need content scrolling just then you need add it manually and hide browser scrollbar

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for late answer)